# Alter Gatsby nodes through Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, yaml, leaflet, gatsby

I have YAML frontmatter in a Gatsby site that is formatted as geo links, like this:

`Location: [La Mia Mamma](geo:51.485978,-0.1721193)`

I want to display these locations on a Leaflet map, for which I think the frontmatter would be better styled as:

`Location: 51.485978,-0.1721193`

for formatting by Leaflet.

How do I transform these nodes into the format I want, for example using Regex? Or am I best transforming them at the point of parsing by Leaflet?

Comment: The transformation seems trivial enough using regex, since all you're doing is cutting out parts you don't want, but whether there's a better way using Leaflet directly I cannot say. For example, using alternation to list the parts you want to get rid of: `/\[[^\]]*]\(geo:|\)$/g` used like `'source'.replace(/\[[^\]]*]\(geo:|\)$/g, '')`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide an example YAML file, so here I provide an example, but am poking a bit in the dark. A simple regex can change the Location lines as desired:

```js
const input =`title: This is from YAML
Location: [La Mia Mamma](geo:51.485978,-0.1721193)
content:
 - item:
     Foo bar
Location: [Mia Mamma!](geo:51.123456,-0.16666)
content:
 - item:
     Foo bar
`;
let result = input.replace(/^(Location: *)[^(]*\(geo:([^)]*)\)/gm, '$1$2');
console.log(result);
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- start of string (here line due to `m` flag
- `(Location: *)` -- capture group 1: literal `Location:`
- `[^(]*` -- scan over everything not `(`
- `\(geo:` -- expect literal `(geo:`
- `([^)]*)` -- capture group 2: scan over everything not `)`
- `\)` -- literal `)`
- `gm` -- flags to match globally (multiple times), and to make regex use newlines as delimiters for start & end of string
- `$1$2` -- replace is capture group 1, followed by capture group 2